# Is it possible to save PHP PEAR SMTP Object as an EML file?

Tags: php, smtp, pear

I'm building an email to send via the PEAR Mail package, using the SMTP option;

```
require_once 'Mail.php';

$email  = Mail::factory('smtp', $this->connection);
$status = $email->send($content['To'], $final['headers'], $final['body']);
```

In addition to firing it off at the mailserver, is there a way of packaging that object  and storing it in the filesystem as an EML file?

Answer (score 0):

No.

---

No, there is no way of packaging that object and storing it in the filesystem as an EML file.

Answer (score 0):

The PEAR Mail package doesn't inherently provide that facility...

But if you use the PEAR Mail_mime package to create your email (it generates both body & headers for use by `Mail::send()`), then it provides a `saveMessage()` method to do just that:

https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/docs/latest/Mail_Mime/Mail_mime.html#methodsaveMessage

You would have to include the `To:` header as an additional parameter when calling this method, or it wouldn't be included in the saved file.

I'm not sure if Mail_mime *always* generates multi-part MIME-format emails, or if it can also generate regular plaintext email if that's all you provide to it, so you might want to check that.